# Storing array in a variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I'm trying to replace the code below

```
$Palette = array(
                 "0"=>array("R"=>188,"G"=>224,"B"=>46,"Alpha"=>100),
                 "1"=>array("R"=>188,"G"=>224,"B"=>46,"Alpha"=>100),
                 "2"=>array("R"=>188,"G"=>224,"B"=>46,"Alpha"=>100),
                 "3"=>array("R"=>188,"G"=>224,"B"=>46,"Alpha"=>100),
                 "4"=>array("R"=>176,"G"=>46,"B"=>224,"Alpha"=>100),
                 );
```

with something similar but different values for the `R`, `G` and `B`. I have written the code below so far as a replacement:

```
$x = '0';
$incrementarray = array("0"=>"A","1"=>"B","2"=>"C","3"=>"D","4"=>"E");

do
{
    if ($correct == $incrementarray[$x])
    {
        $colour[$x] = '"'.$x.'"=>array("R"=>188,"G"=>224,"B"=>46,"Alpha"=>100),';
    }
    else 
    {
    $colour[$x] =  '"'.$x.'"=>array("R"=>255,"G"=>51,"B"=>51,"Alpha"=>100),';
    }
    $x++;
}
while ($x <= '4');

$allcolours = $colour[0].$colour[1].$colour[2].$colour[3].$colour[4];
```

however, when I implement it into my script using the line below , it doesn't work.

```
$Palette = array($allcolours);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = '0';
$incrementarray = array("0"=>"A","1"=>"B","2"=>"C","3"=>"D","4"=>"E");

do
{
    if ($correct == $incrementarray[$x])
    {
        $Pallete[$x] = array("R"=>188,"G"=>224,"B"=>46,"Alpha"=>100);
    }
    else 
    {
    $Pallete[$x] =  array("R"=>255,"G"=>51,"B"=>51,"Alpha"=>100);
    }
    $x++;
}
while ($x <= '4');
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a little excessive usage of $x.
as a matter of fact, you don't need that variable at all

```
$Palette = array();
$incrementarray = array("0"=>"A","1"=>"B","2"=>"C","3"=>"D","4"=>"E");
foreach ($incrementarray as $value)
{
    if ($correct == $value)
    {
        $Palette[] = array("R"=>188,"G"=>224,"B"=>46,"Alpha"=>100);
    }
    else 
    {
        $Palette[] = array("R"=>255,"G"=>51,"B"=>51,"Alpha"=>100);
    }
}
```

you need to create array, **not the PHP code to create array.**